# how do I use curl to test my Rails controller create action.. or can I use rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl, rspec

Please bear with me as the Rails guide chooses to not even mention the create action in their API section. My goal is to build a RESTFUL API from which content can be created. Here is what the form looks like after `$ curl myapp`

```
<form class="new_blog" id="new_blog" action="/blog" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
    <label for="blog_input">Input a String</label> 
    <textarea class="input-field" name="blog[input]" id="blog_input">
</textarea>
  <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Create Blog" />
</form>
```

I want to POST content through curl... or... can I test this somehow through Rspec?

The goal is that I have a RESTFUL API that allows content to be created through HTTP requests and then gives an HTTP response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Ruby HTTP Cheat Sheet](http://www.rubyinside.com/nethttp-cheat-sheet-2940.html) and create various type of requests directly from Ruby, no need to go to curl for that.